# how to change Lab color space to RGB 0-255

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision, colormath

I have Lab dataset: val_lab_2    like that:

```
[[ 7.803e+01  3.100e-01  1.382e+01]
 [ 6.697e+01 -7.400e+00  2.750e+01]
 [ 5.631e+01 -1.804e+01  1.599e+01]
 [ 6.701e+01  2.650e+00  2.913e+01]
 [ 6.564e+01  1.660e+00  2.540e+01]
 [ 3.537e+01  2.050e+01  3.784e+01]
 [ 4.178e+01  2.251e+01  4.438e+01]
 [ 6.129e+01  1.261e+01  5.934e+01]
 [ 4.269e+01  5.120e+00  4.995e+01]...]
```

I want to change it to RGB 0-255, so I use colormath package:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, XYZColor, LabColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

val_rgb_2 = []
for lab_list in val_lab_2:
       lab = LabColor(*[component for component in lab_list])
       rgb = convert_color(lab, sRGBColor)
       rgb_list = [255*color for color in rgb.get_value_tuple()]
       val_rgb_2.append(rgb_list)
val_rgb_2 = np.array(val_rgb_2)
print(val_rgb_2)
```

the result shows:

```
[[201.44003158 192.14717152 167.2643737 ]
 [163.51015463 166.15931613 112.52909259]
 [109.8451797  143.64817993 106.17872676]
 [181.45664244 160.44644464 110.27374654]
 [174.70091435 157.51328159 113.65978481]
 [122.18753543  69.26114552  19.79086107]
 [143.2650315   82.85139354  20.50673141]
 [187.60706038 138.48640317  31.06087929]...]
```

However, I think it is not correct, because I have a label, first few rows shows it should be:

natural white 100% wool,blue-violet flowers,blue flowers,flowers,whole plant,peels,peels,peels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use this [website](https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/) to:

- insert the `LAB` values
- check the `RGB` values that the website gives you
- check the color associated with the `LAB`/`RGB` you have insert

I have done a check and the conversion between the two matrix you wrote is correct.
For example let's try with the second element of the list above, which it should be labeled as *blue-violet flowers*:

```
[ 6.697e+01 -7.400e+00  2.750e+01]
```

[image]

The conversion is correct; I have some doubts regarding the labels.